# Average of a column without using csv module

Tags: csv

I have a csv file with data arranged into columns. I need to calculate the average of all the data from one specific column. How do i do that without using the csv module?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux, you can use `awk` to sum up any column and divide by number of records.

For column 1, you can do the following.

```
awk -F',' '{sum += $1} END {print sum / NR}' Input.csv
```

Comment: * `END { print sum / NR }`